# Complex MySQL Query, Multi Table - How Do I Write This Relational Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm having issues writing this query, it's an odd relation that I can't figure out. I'm wondering if it would be better to just use two mysql queries and merge the results with php?... Anyways.. so here we go.

Here's the tables we're using:

```
- media -
id 
userId 
accessKey 
internalName 
type
created 
modified

- reposts - 
id
userId
mediaId
created

- users - 
id
username
```

Basically, what I want to do is get a result set of media items associated with the user who posted it, and then ALSO, in the same result set, include additional rows for media items that have been reposted, and then for reposted media items, instead of associating the media.userId of the media item for the username association, associate the reposts.userId as the username.

Here's a rough idea to illustrate, these two example queries below need to work as 1 to provide a combined result set.

```
SELECT media.*, users.username,
0 AS reposted
FROM media
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = media.userId

SELECT media.id, media.accessKey, media.internalName, media.type, media.modified, users.username, reposts.userId, reposts.created,
1 AS reposted
FROM reposts
LEFT JOIN media ON media.id = reposts.mediaId
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = reposts.userId
```

How would I go about doing this? Or would I be better off using 2 queries and merging the results with PHP?

Comment: Can I say you want some sort of facebook wall or twitter kind of functionality, where my posts and posts that I repost or retweet are also shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION in your query, but UNION requires the same number of columns (and same data type if I recall correctly) on both queries:

```
(SELECT media.id, media.accessKey, media.internalName, media.type, media.modified, users.username, users.id, media.created,
0 AS reposted
FROM media
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = media.userId)
UNION
(SELECT media.id, media.accessKey, media.internalName, media.type, media.modified, users.username, reposts.userId, reposts.created,
1 AS reposted
FROM reposts
LEFT JOIN media ON media.id = reposts.mediaId
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = reposts.userId)
```

Comment: correct on column count and data type, but also need to be in same column order unless explicit column names included in the union query, otherwise the columns are implied same order as first query

Comment: EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED! I had totally forgotten about unions. Thank you!